# Does cvQueryFrame advance the current frame?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to learn OpenCV using an O'Reilley book and am finding the sample programs raise as many questions as they answer. In a very basic program to show a video:

```
#include <highgui.h>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char** argv){
  std::string name = "Example 2";

  cvNamedWindow(name.c_str(),CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  CvCapture*  capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1]);
  IplImage* frame;

  while(1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if ( !frame ) break;
    cvShowImage (name.c_str(), frame);
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if (c == 27) break; //User hits ESC key - ASCII value 27
  }

  cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
  cvDestroyWindow(name.c_str());

}
```

I find myself wondering why I ever see more than a single frame. Everything I read online about cvQueryFrame says it retrieves the current frame. No where have I seen anything about how/when/where the "current" frame advances.

Does cvQueryFrame act more like reading from a file or stream, in that it reads data and then prepares to read the next piece of data, or does the current frame advance in some other way?

Comment: It is always recommended to use new C++ interface instead of outdated old C. You can start from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)

Comment: I think you are right! This function reads the current frame(if any) and also decode it(in order to show it) and then it is prepared to read for the next frame in the next iteration, I think is something like [grab](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#grab) and [retrieve](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#retrieve) together for the current frame!

Comment: @Constantine - Thanks. I just found a reference explaining that cvGrab 'advances' the frame...